Swift own version of startMonitoringVisits to run in background
We are building an app for tracking in the background all the visits so that we can do timekeeping based on GPS. I have created an service which is managing this. In the past we have used
locationManager.delegate = self
locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
locationManager.showsBackgroundLocationIndicator = true
locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
locationManager.startMonitoringVisits();

Problem with this function is that is does not work good enough. So we have made our own which is started from swift UI interface and fetching an coord every 5 minutes and then compares with the previous one. This is working properly.
But the another problem arises is that when the app is swiped away the process is getting killed. But for some reason we cannot find the solution to make sure that IOS is started the process again automatically in background when the app is killed.
We have changed the app delegate to take care of this but this solution does not appear to work:
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        BGTaskScheduler.shared.register(forTaskWithIdentifier: "com.myapp.refresh", using: nil) { task in
            self.handleBackgroundFetch(task: task as! BGAppRefreshTask)
        }
        scheduleBackgroundFetch()
        return true
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        scheduleBackgroundFetch()
    }

    func scheduleBackgroundFetch() {
        let request = BGAppRefreshTaskRequest(identifier: "com.myapp.refresh")
        request.earliestBeginDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 5 * 60) 
        do {
            try BGTaskScheduler.shared.submit(request)
        } catch {
            print("Could not schedule app refresh: \(error)")
        }
    }

    func handleBackgroundFetch(task: BGAppRefreshTask) {
        scheduleBackgroundFetch()
        
        let queue = OperationQueue()
        queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1
        
        let operation = BlockOperation {
            MyAppGeoFenceLocationManager.shared.runLocationManager()
        }
        
        task.expirationHandler = {
            queue.cancelAllOperations()
        }
        
        queue.addOperation(operation)
        task.setTaskCompleted(success: !operation.isCancelled)
    }
}

What is a proper way to solve this problem and run an service in background and restart when killed for whatever reason? Basically we want to recreate the startMonitoringVisits method in our own way with different logic. Thanks for the help!
Note:

We added the com.myapp.refresh in the plist
Onder Signing & Capabilities the Location Updates, Background fetch and Background processing are checked


Try enabling significant location change monitoring. Note that you don't need to show the background location indicator if you have "always" location permission. In my experience the visits api is very reliable as long as the user has granted always permission.

Beyond Paul's excellent points, you generally aren't going to be able to reproduce startMonitoringVisits better than the OS's version. There is, by design, no way to run a process every 5 minutes. Using significant change monitoring is extremely useful, but it only gets triggered on the order of 500m or so. (More or less when the user changes cell towers.) The correct tool is startMonitoringVisits().

Ah thanks. We will also try with the significant location monitoring. Hope that one will be better then startMonitoringVisits.

Yes, my suggestion is to use significant location monitoring to relaunch your app, but it is not going to be a replacement for visit monitoring. Visit monitoring is an amazing api. It can tell the difference between "stopped at a coffee shop" and "stopped at a traffic light near a coffee shop" and can provide the start time if a visit.  And it will deliver visits on app launch. I think your problem is trying to keep the app running at all times. This is not needed with visits. You just need to give the user a reason to open your app and your delegate will get the visits delivered
